# CSS - wrap blocks to a single column when the blocks cannot all fit on a single row

Tags: css

Suppose I have these blocks in a container:

```
$| Luke Skywalker | Princess Leia | Chewbacca |     $
```

The dollar signs (`$`) mark the width of the container. The pipe signs (`|`) mark the width of each block.

Now I shrink the container (maybe because the user shrunk the browser window) and it's no longer wide enough for all 3 blocks on the same row. A naïve implementation based on flexbox (`display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;`) gives me this:

```
$   | Luke Skywalker | Princess Leia |   $
$              | Chewbacca |             $
```

But this is ugly for my tastes. I would rather get this:

```
$           | Luke Skywalker |           $
$           | Princess Leia |            $
$             | Chewbacca |              $
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect using pure CSS?

Note that the blocks are dynamically generated. I do not know in advance the total number of blocks that will appear or the content of each block.

Comment: yes : media query

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<style>

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.block::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can use `width : calc(100% / 3)` Instead hardcoding the width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-box {max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;display: flex;box-sizing: border-box;justify-content: space-around;flex-wrap: wrap;}

.flex-box .flex-list {
    background: #000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
Use this bro
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="flex-list"></div>
  <div class="flex-list"></div>
  <div class="flex-list"></div>
</div>
```